# Max Clique - NP Problem

Tags: np-complete

The question is to show that the recognition version of Clique is in NP.

I have started with a graph G=(V,E) and integer k such that G does have a clique C of cardinality k. How to proceed further from here?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Because of the capital letters, it took me some time to understand that this is not about the recognition by the mathematical community of a guy called Max Clique who claimed to have solved the P=NP problem...

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that given a set $C$ of vertices, you can check in polynomial
time whether $C$ is a clique of cardinality $k$.

Comment: Isn't this only half of the problem though?  How would I give an evidence of the nonexistence of a $k$-clique that can be checked in polynomial time?

Comment: @hardmath NP means that a "yes" answer can be checked in polynomial time.  If a "no" answer can be checked in polynomial time, the problem is in co-NP.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you even try to find the solution in wikipedia?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#NP-completeness